# pdo fetch column names from table that fit a pattern using only query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Is it possible to fetch all column names that have a pattern? For example, fetch all columns that start with 'allow'. I would like it to only use pure pdo query and not an php array filter.

```
  $prepare=$database->query("show columns from TABLENAME like 'allow%'");
  $fetched=$prepare->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some shared hosts don't let you use the info schema, in those situations you can use `show columns`, which looks like this.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `database`.`table` WHERE Field like '%access'
```

Answer (score 0):

`information_schema.columns` holds column and table structure information.

```
$prepare=$database->query("select column_name from information_schema.columns where table_name='TABLENAME' and column_name like 'allow%'");
$fetched=$prepare->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($fetched);
```